# SSL certificate information

Tags: ssl

I was doing some research, but nothing answers my question.
Given url address (https://www.google.com) how do I get information about SSL certificate, when I have almost no tools to do so?
What I am able to do:
Send GET / POST (Patch, delete) request to certain url with no possibility to use ports.
apply header and parameters to request.
Receive response with header.
Well. thats it.
I (have to) use Deluge as language, with no posibilities using external libraries.

What are my options on getting information about Certificate (Start Date, Expiration Date, Organization, etc) using these tools?
Thanks

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/661978/displaying-a-remote-ssl-certificate-details-using-cli-tools Seems relevent

Comment: Yeah, openssl seems good, but I cannot use it.

Comment: You should expand on `What are my options` in that case. Seems like you have limited options